# javascript, Simple if else statement

Tags: javascript

I am just getting started With JavaScript and I would like help with this basic if/else statement. I believe the syntax is off? I need it to read True.

```
if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === )
{
        console.log("The answer makes sense!")
}
else 
{
    console.log( "Error Error Error")
}
```

Comment: if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === )
{
    console.log("The answer makes sense!");
}else{
    console.log('Error Error Error');
    }
}

Comment: it's close, but you need to finish the if. Perhaps you meant to say `if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 2)`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Ok you have an if statement, what is the condition you want to check? If you had a number on the right of `===`, this expression would be evaluated as a true/false, which is what you are looking for. The question is which is this number?

Comment: @SherrieChenault if you want a good answer you need to first explain what is the goal of this piece of code. Explain what you wanted to compare in the if statement. Then we will be able to figure out how to fix it so that it makes sense.

Comment: thank you, I certainly found a solution thanks to all the feed back.

Answer (score 1):

Working code is :

```
<script>
if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 2)
{
    console.log("The answer makes sense!"); //or
    //alert("The answer makes sense!");
}
else 
{
    console.log( "Error Error Error"); //or
    //alert("Error Error Error");
}
</script>
```